# Как работают галереи изображений на сайтах?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Я только начал свой путь в веб-программировании и на данный момент меня интересует вопрос, на который я так и не могу найти внятного ответа, по крайней мере задавая вопрос в той форме, в какой я это представляю.
Как же работают современные веб-галереи, содержащие огромное количество картинок? То есть, как, например, вот этот сайт - https://anime-pictures.net/ (непосредственно его содержимое не важно, мне только нравится как он устроен и оформлен), где при нажатии на каждую картинку браузер переходит на другую страницу, на которой есть свои комментарии и так далее. Я уже в каком-то из обучающих видео слышал, что было бы весьма глупо создавать тысячи html страниц для каждой картинки, но, увы, я так ничего и не понял.
Может быть, есть и какое-то видео или статья на эту тему, на предоставление которой я буду вам благодарен, однако если вы разъясните понятным языком непосредственно мой вопрос, да ещё и с примерами кода, то буду вам прям очень благодарен.

Comment: А вообще принцип работы динамических сайтов, отличия от статических знаете?

Comment: Примерно понимаю отличия(на всякий случай ещё глянул пару видео и почитал на сайте, вдруг понимаю что-то не так), но так и не понял как это работает(

Comment: Вообще, везде вижу уроки динамически галерей, но совсем не похожих на ту, что я привёл в пример. То есть там лишь открывается картинка на полный экран, однако это не отдельная страница с возможностью комментирования, оценивания и т.д.

Comment: Естественно, я понимаю что комментирование и оценивание потом нужно будет добавить связывая с БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принцип прост, у Вас есть к примеру категории Аниме, Фильмы, Авто, у каждой категории есть название в базе данных, пишите функцию которая выгребает все сначала по одной категории потом по другой, потом разбираете в цикле и выводите на клиенте, без базы данных тут не обойтись, в базу рекомендую класть только названия картинок, а путь подставлять в верстке, так же хранить по категориям, чтобы снизить нагрузку если картинок будет слишком много.

Грубо говоря, загружаете картинки в  папку через обработчик, во время загрузки он кладет названия в базу по логике, дальше как описано выше, разбираете через функцию, ну а дальше лимиты, сортировка и тп если надо